# Is Oracle an example of DBMS or RDBMS?

Tags: oracle, rdbms, database

I am confused about the terms "DBMS" and "RDBMS". What exactly is the difference between them and more specifically, can oracle be called a DBMS or an RDBMS? If it is an example of an RDBMS, then what are examples of a DBMS?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_Database

Answer (score 4):

I would think Oracle is both: **DBMS** and **RDBMS**. Relational databases (RDBMS) are a subset of more generic databases management systems (DBMS).

Answer (score 4):

For a quick summary of what a RDBMS is, i'd think wikipedia is a good a source as any:

> A relational database management
>   system (RDBMS) is a database
>   management system (DBMS) that is based
>   on the relational model as introduced
>   by E. F. Codd. Most popular commercial
>   and open source databases currently in
>   use are based on the relational
>   database model.
>
> A short definition of an RDBMS may be
>   a DBMS in which data is stored in the
>   form of tables and the relationship
>   among the data is also stored in the
>   form of tables.

from: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system

Comment: My teacher said, in RDBMS data is stored in the form of tuples. So which technique is used to store data in DBMS (if not tuple)?

Answer (score 4):

- DBMS includes Object Orientated or Hierarchical or NoSQL DBMS.
- RDBMS means those DBMS that are Relational (more or less).

One aspect of an RDBMS is that it stores its metadata in tables and access them via the query language.

```
SELECT * FROM sys.tables, SELECT * FROM DUAL etc
```

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with this statement. Oracle supports NoSQL (JSON), Graph and Text. Other DBMSs that are NoSQL and hierarchical also have Query languages. The definition of what a database is has become very blurred.

Answer (score 2):

DBMS: software that helps to store data in a database in the form of tables, manage databases on a single system or across a local network. They are used to manage small amount of data and are used in small business applications. eg: MsExcel

RDBMS: a DBMS that also allows relationships to be established across different tables and allows querying of the table to extract certain data. They are useful to efficiently manage vast amount of data and are used in large business applications. eg: Oracle, MySQL.

So essentially, RDBMS is a superset of DBMS.

Comment: Hi @Ankita. I would disagree with your point that RDBMS are superset of DBMS. In fact, DBMS are superset of RDBMS.

Answer (score 1):

Any SQL product is considered to be a RDBMS. Therefore, Oracle is a RDBMS.

The confusing thing is that the 'R' in 'RDBMS' stands for 'relational' and SQL has many features that make it fundamentally at odds with current relational theory. However, the concept 'SQL means RDBMS' is too well established, the damage is done. Therefore, a new term was coined: TRDBMS where 'TR' stands for 'truly relational'. Oracle is not a TRDBMS.

Comment: In what way is Oracle not a TRDBMS?

Comment: @WillSheppard: In a nutshell, because Oracle's database language is a SQL dialect and SQL lacks essential elements of a truly relation language and includes things that violate the relational model. For example, an operation in a relational language takes relations as arguments and results in a relation; the same cannot be said for SQL e.g. 'INNER JOIN' results in a data structure that is not named by the SQL standards but is not a relation because it can have duplicate column names, duplicate rows and nulls.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle is an example of RDBMS.Example systems are SQL Server, Oracle , MySQL, MariaDB, SQLite. And for DBMS example systems are dBase, Microsoft Acces, LibreOffice Base, FoxPro.

Answer (score 0):

DBMS is a Database Management System.  "R" adds Relational into the mix.  Any RDBMS is therefore a DBMS.  Oracle is a relational database, so it is an RDBMS.

Comment: Oracle also supports lots of Non Relational approaches as well. NoSQL, Graph, Text.. As previous commentators point out it's in both sets.

Answer (score 0):

DBMS = Database Management System.  In my mind this is a generic term which would include *any* sort of database, including relational databases (such as MySQL, Oracle, PostgreSQL, SQL Server, etc), hierarchical databases (such as IMS), network (example: IDMS), object-oriented, NoSQL, and others.

RDBMS = Relational Database Management System.  To me this is a sub-term of DBMS, including only those database products which implement (some form of) the relational model.  Examples would be Oracle, MySQL, SQL Server, PostgreSQL.

SO, to answer your question "Is Oracle an example of DBMS or RDBMS", the answer is "Yes".  :-)

Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

Supporting Select * from  System.table-x  or user-table alone does not qualify a product as a Relational database.  SELECT support can be implemnted by any DBMS (non-relational inclusive). As for meta data, again an Online Query SQL front allowed anyone to do a SELECT * FROM USER_047 (against the meta data in Dictionary) to IDMS as early as 1984. That time IDMS was a pure CODASYL network database.  IDMS did come up with  full sql support in the 1990s with SQL DDL and DML in native form.

Pure RDBMS  must support fullscale DDL and DML using SQL like commands (SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT and DELETE) and GRANT, REVOKE etc for Access Control.  Besides one could insist that no other access should be allowed. That is one should not be allowed to read any data if one doesnot go through the DBMS software of the product.  Many PC databases of the 1980s fail this test. They were all some kind of file systems with some access (Sql or not ).

In a real DBMS, the database software alone should be able to update or even 'see' data. Operating system's own file programs should not be allowed to browse through the data in ASCII / EBCDIC form.   DBMS in a way takes control of the whole storage areas of the files which is 'loaned' from the operating system.  OS access methods are involved at the lowest level, but here user cannot intercept.

Answer (score -2):

DBMS

1. It doesn't allow relations between the tables.
2. follows object oriented and hierarchical model, e.g. Foxpro

RDBMS

1. It allows relations between the tables
2. follows relational model, e.g. Oracle,SQL Server

Comment: Wrong. In the relational model, a table IS a relation (following the mathematical definition). There is nothing like relations between tables. A DBMS is just a database management system. A RDBMS is a DBMS following the relational model defined by Edgar F. Codd.

Answer (score -2):

How is it different from a normal DBMS?

- RDBMS allows for normalization of data.
- RDBMS maintains a relation between the data stored in its tables. A
  normal DBMS does not provide any such link. It blankly stores data is
  its files.
- Structured approach of RDBMS supports a distributed database unlike a
  normal database management system.

> So oracle is an RDBMS.
>   [See 25 examples of most popular RDBMS and DBMS](http://whatisdbms.com/examples-of-popular-database-management-systems/)

Comment: Hi @sumit. There are certain issues with your answer. For example, both DBMS and RDBMS store data as files but they provide different kind of abstractions to the end user. Similarly, both DBMS and RDBMS can be distributed.

Comment: Hey Shagun, its great that you got my mistake otherwise this answer must have created problem for newbies :) I am editing this answer thanks again.

Comment: Oracle Database supports NoSQL approaches as well. NoSQL, Graph, Text... IT exists in both sets. They aren't exclusive.